# Rails nested routes with multiple categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ancestry

i'm trying to figure out how i can get nested routes like this:

```
match '/:category_id/:subcategory_id/:id', via: 'get', controller: 'categories', action: 'index', as: 'category'
```

the subcategory and the id shouldn't be required. it should be possible to get:

- category index
- subcategory index
- id show

category and subcategory should use the same controller action. category and subcategory of course use the same ancestry / tree model.

i'm a little bit lost on this one. any hints would be great!

Comment: It sounds like nested resources would get you most of what you want:
resources :category do
  resources :subcategory
end

Have you considered/tried this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like nested resources would get you most of what you want:

```
resources :category do 
  resources :subcategory 
end
```

Have you considered/tried this?

For more on nested resources, including some insight into how to restrict what routes are exposed:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Comment: hm this would give me a route like /categories/my-category/subcategories/my-subcat and it sounds complicated to create the path like subcategory_category_path('bla','bla1') and what if subcategory not set?

Comment: Ah... ok.  Well, the last issue wouldn't be a problem with this solution, but it may be that you're looking for a different solution none-the-less.  Unfortunately, I don't have the time at the moment to give it to you.

Comment: One tip:  you could implement what I suggested (or some variation on it) and then run `rake routes` from the command line and see if it produces the results you are hoping for.